# NumPy -- индексирование множества элементов в многомерных массивов по списку их координат

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, индексация, индексы

Пусть имеется многомерный массив:

```
arr = numpy.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
```

Хочется получить из него одномерный массив, причем индексы элементов массива `arr`, которые должны присутствовать в новом массиве, приведены в списке:

```
ind = [(0, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3), (0, 2, 2)]
```

При этом, если пробовать обращаться по отдельности к элементам списка `ind`, то результат будет ожидаемым и желаемым:

```
arr[ind[0]] == 5
arr[ind[1]] == 23
arr[ind[2]] == 10
```

А вот если попробовать сразу создать массив следующим образом:

```
new_arr = arr[ind]
```

Выдаст ошибку `IndexError`

Можно, конечно, поступить иначе:

```
new_arr = numpy.array([])
for j in ind:
    new_arr = numpy.append(new_arr, arr[j])
```

И получить желаемый массив

```
new_arr == [5, 23, 10]
```

Однако, непонятно почему появляется ошибка `IndexError`, ведь в одномерном случае всё прекрасно работает:

```
arr_1d = numpy.arange(9)
ind_1d = [1, 3, 7, 4]

new_arr_1d = arr_1d[ind_1d]
new_arr_1d == [1, 3, 7, 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [139]: arr[tuple(np.array(ind).T)]
Out[139]: array([ 5, 23, 10])
```

или так:

```
In [142]: arr[np.array(ind).T.tolist()]
Out[142]: array([ 5, 23, 10])
```

или так:

```
In [152]: arr[tuple(zip(*ind))]
Out[152]: array([ 5, 23, 10])
```

Смысл в том, что при индексировании 2+ мерных массивов в качестве первого индекса мы указываем вектор (1D массив) координат по первому измерению/оси, в качестве второго индексы/координаты по второму измерению и т.д.

```
In [145]: np.array(ind).T.tolist()
Out[145]: [[0, 1, 0], [1, 2, 2], [1, 3, 2]]
```